# If $1 \leq p \leq \infty$ then there does not exist $c>0$ such that $||x||_{\infty} \leq c||x||_p \ \ \forall x \in C[a,b].$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> If $1 \leq p \leq \infty$ then there does not exist $c>0$ such that $$||x||_{\infty} \leq c||x||_p \ \ \forall x \in C[a,b].$$

I have found an counter example for the case $p=1$ but struggling to find example for a general $p$.

Comment: What is your counter example for the case $p=1$ ? One may assume $[a,b]=[0,1]$ for a start.

Comment: yes I used [0,1] for the example

Comment: $f_k(t) = t^k$...

Answer (score 1):

Note that a change of variable allows us to assume that $[a,b]=[0,1]$. Using your example $f_k(t)=t^k$, compute $\lVert f_k \rVert_\infty$ and $\lVert f_k \rVert_p$. Conclude.

Comment: I am thinking to use $t^{k/p}$...will it work??

Comment: $t^k$ should definitely work. The point is to take $k$ big enough.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Without loss of generality, $[a,b]=[0,1]$. For fixed $p \geq 1$ choose $x \in C[0,1]$ such that $\|x\|_p = 1$. Define

$$x_n(t) := n^{1/p} \cdot x \left( nt \right), \qquad t \in [0,1].$$

Show that there does not exist $c>0$ such that

$$\|x_n\|_{\infty} \leq c \|x_n\|_p \qquad \text{for all $n \geq 1$.}$$

Comment: $x(nt)$ is ill-defined whenever $n$ is too big.

Comment: @tristan Consider the continuous extension to $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. set the function zero outside $[0,1]$).